# How to assign constant value to bus in Quartus II schematic editor?

Tags: fpga, schematics, quartus

No matter what I try, Quartus just spams errors similar to this:

Error (12009): Node "modulus[31]" is missing source

[image: what I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: And what is TEST_WIDTH? 31?

Answer (score 3):

Create a LPM_CONSTANT block from the Symbol tool, shown below.

[image: Adding the LPM_CONSTANT block to the block diagram file (BDF).]

Then double click the symbol to go to symbol properties and enter the desired value and bus width, shown below.

[image: How to enter the constant value into the LPM_CONSTANT block.]